# I have created a job template for aws elemental mediaconvert. How do I use the template name in .net core to create a job?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, .net-core

Is there any way to use existing created template name to create a job in .net code instead of rewriting the output setting. I even used chatgpt but I think code there is outdated. It is showing me to use template name like:

```
                    {
                        TemplateName = "YourTemplateName" // Specify the name of your template
                    }
```

But I am not getting any property with name of *TemplateName*

My Code:

```
 CreateJobRequest createJobRequest = new CreateJobRequest
            {
                Role = "ROLE:ARN"
            };
            string mediaConvertEndpoint = "MediaConvertEndPoint";

            JobSettings jobSettings = new JobSettings
            {
                AdAvailOffset = 0,
                TimecodeConfig = new TimecodeConfig
                {
                    Source = TimecodeSource.EMBEDDED
                }
            };
            createJobRequest.Settings = jobSettings;

            #region OutputGroup
            OutputGroup ofg = new OutputGroup
            {
                Name = "File Group",
                OutputGroupSettings = new OutputGroupSettings
                {
                    Type = OutputGroupType.FILE_GROUP_SETTINGS,
                    FileGroupSettings = new FileGroupSettings
                    {
                        Destination = outputPath
                    }
                }
            };
            Output output = new Output
            {
                NameModifier = "_1",
            };
```

Thank You.

Comment: No worry guys, just have to add *JobTemplate* in CreateJobRequest object
eg:
```
CreateJobRequest createJobRequest = new CreateJobRequest
            {
                Role = "ROLE:ARN",
                JobTemplate= "TEMPLATE NAME"
            }
```